# How to remove everything EXCEPT contents of brackets from a filename

Tags: string, file, batch-file

I have a folder of about 1700 audio files, in the following format:

```
CybirdConanVoice2Cri#1 (AGA_SE1).wav
CybirdConanVoice2Cri#2 (AGA_SE10).wav
CybirdConanVoice2Cri#3 (AGA_SE11).wav
```

I want to remove the first part of every file name, leaving just the contents of the brackets. For example:

```
AGA_SE1.wav
AGA_SE10.wav
AGA_SE11.wav
```

I did some research and it seems like maybe batch would be the best way to tackle this problem. I don't have much experience with batch, but I figured I would try and teach myself enough to solve this problem.

I found numerous questions on StackOverflow asking how to remove everything INSIDE the brackets, but nothing on how to keep only the bracketed text. After fiddling around for a few hours, I put together this code:

```
cd C:\Users\ etc etc
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
  set f=%%a
  
  set g=%f:*(=%
  
  ren "%%a" "!g!"
)
```

However, when I tried this on one of the files, I ended up with this: `CybirdConanVoice2Cri#1 (=`. I was wondering if anyone with more experience could help me out, or point out where I went wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the output of the first `FOR` command into a `FOR /F` command which allows you to split up strings using the `DELIMS` option. `FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%G in ("%%a") Do ....`

Comment: Thank you @Squashman! I've pretty much got it working now - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*(*)*" '
 ) DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=2delims=()" %%r IN ("%%a") DO ECHO REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%%r%%~xa"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The first `for` assigns each filename matching `*(*)*` in the source directory to `%%a` in turn. The `delims=` ensures that the entire filename is assigned.

The inner `for` analyses the filename in `%%a`, tokenising using `(` and `)` (the delimiters) and assigning the second token to `%%r`.

Then rename (`Echo`ed only for verification)

Your code - might have worked, but since `f` is changed in the loop, you would need to use `set g=!f:*(=!` and then you've still got the `)` to remove. Assuming there are no files of the pattern `whatever (required)somethingelse.wav` then the rename could then have been to `!g:~0,-5!.wav` where the `-5` means "all but the last 5 characters, ie. `).wav`.

The `dir` approach builds a list of filenames in memory, then processes the list. The `for in (pattern)` approach can cause problems where a renamed file can be reprocessed since the names are processed in order-encountered.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your code, you just needed to change your `f` variable to the filename only, then use delayed expansion for your new `g` variable whilst removing the last character, then finally add the extension back on.

```batch-file
cd C:\Users\etc\etc
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
    set f=%%~na
    set g=!f:*(=!
    ren "%%a" "!g:~,-1!%%~xa"
)
```

You could have also made your `cd` command, and file glob a little bit more robust, and doublequoted your things for additional safety.*

```batch-file
cd /d "C:\Users\etc\etc"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("?*(*).wav") do (
    set "f=%%~na"
    set "g=!f:*(=!"
    ren "%%a" "!g:~,-1!%%~xa"
)
```